# Why does Facebook not show the image in my Google Apps Script link?

Tags: facebook, google-apps-script

In an effort to answer the title question, I have put together the following simple Google Apps Script:

Code.gs:

```
var params;
function doGet(e) {
  params=e.parameter;
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('Web App').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  return html;
}
```

index.html:

```
<div>
 <h2>The Gettysburg Address</h2>
 <p>
  <img src="<?!= params.url ?>" style="float: left;">
 <p>
 Four score and seven years ago, our forefathers brought forth upon this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated to the proposition that all 
 men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a great civil war testing whether that nation or any nation so conceived and so dedicated can long endure.  We
 met on a great battlefield of that war.
 </p>
</div>
```

I publish the script and then insert the URL (to which I have appended:

?url=url_of_my_image

into a browser address bar and it all works perfectly.  However, when I insert the same URL (with the querystring appended) into the Facebook debugger, Facebook refuses to recognize the image.  Anyone know why that is and (more importantly) what I can do about it?

Thanks for any input.

```
... doug
```

Comment: Are you trying to post an image to Facebook?  Why are you using the Facebook debugger?

Comment: No.  I am not trying to post an image to Facebook.  I'm merely trying to understand why it is that when I link from Facebook to the Google Apps Script that I posted, Facebook doesn't grab the image from the script as one would normally expect when posting a link.  The script works just fine standalone including displaying the image.  Also, the link posted to Facebook works just fine as a link.  It's just that the image that I would normally expect to be present in the FB link is missing.  Im trying to understand why and hopefully do something about it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

that is not a direct link to an image. its a link that returns an html file which inside has a link.
you would need a `contentService` from apps script to return an image mimetype or to return directly an html type.

Comment: I understand that it's not a direct link to an image.  I'm sure that a direct link to an image would work.  The thing is, when one posts a link on Facebook, Facebook pretty much always grabs an image from the link (assuming that the link has an image) and includes it with the link posted on FB.  It's a nice touch.  There has been much discussion about how FB selects the image.  That's not an issue here since my script only has 1 image.  Anyway, I'm just trying to find out why FB doesn't grab the image from my link and post it with the link on FB as it usually does.  Thanks.

Comment: on apps script, the html file is not served right away. there is ajax going on, which wont happen with contentService. You might be able to avoid the ajax and/or auth redirects if you publish the script with public and anonymous access. You might also be able to use contentService to return an html with the link inside.

Comment: FWIW, this test script has always been published with public and anonymous access.  I have never used the contentService.

Comment: FWIW, this test script has always been published with public and anonymous access.  I have never used the contentService.  However, from my limited understanding, I think there would be problems.  First, I don't think that the contentService supports templating.  That would be a show stopper for me.  Also, I'm concerned that I may not be able to work with a file as I can with the HTML service.  I think that it's a big problem that GAS and Facebook do not play nicely together in this regard.  Thanks.

Comment: regarding templating i havent tried this suggestion but might work to use the htmlService templating but then just use it to get the final html and return with contentService. but the page would then might not work with google.script.run and such.

Comment: Yes.  Upon reflection, I think that it's important that GAS can be built with the HtmlService and still play nicely with FB so that FB users can link to them in the same way tht they link to all other content.  Does this rise to the level of being some sort of a bug?  If so, is it a bug with GAS or a bug with FB?  Thaniks.

Comment: hmm Id try making a non-gas test html page that changes its dom after an ajax and see if fb picks up the img in the new dom. I doubt it. if so, i doubt fb will accept its a bug, and gas probably has an architecture that forces an ajax so will prob say its by design and to use contentService.

Comment: Flash!! I actually got this thing to display *An* image.  It's not the image I want and I have no idea where it comes from (it's an image of the head and shoulders of a silhouetted  man); but, none the less, it's an image.  I got there by removing the ! from <?=! when I grab the URL in my template.  Now that I have gotten it to grab an image, maybe I can figure out how to get it to grab the image that i want.